# Trouble unmasking Websocket data in C

Tags: c, websocket

I have a Websocket server I am developing.  I have a function to handle the unmasking of the websocket data.

I have some debug code active.  The output of the debug code when sending "?jog,0,10,10\n" over the socket is is:

databefore: ▒▒cy▒▒\ðOI▒▒SU▒▒i
dataafter: ▒{U

The code is as follows:

```
void sock_unmasking_data(struct sock_data *sockdat, int dataCount) {
    unsigned int ix;
    unsigned char mask[4];
    int rc;
    log_printf(3,"databefore: %s",sockdat->buffer);
    dataCount = ((unsigned char) sockdat->buffer[1]) & 0x7f;
    mask[0] = sockdat->buffer[2];
    mask[1] = sockdat->buffer[3];
    mask[2] = sockdat->buffer[4];
    mask[3] = sockdat->buffer[5];
    if(dataCount <= 126) { // Unmask the payload for a 126 byte message or smaller                  
        for (ix = 0; ix < dataCount; ix++) {
            sockdat->buffer[6 + ix] ^= mask[ix % 4];
        }
        rc = asprintf(&sockdat->dataUnmasked, "%.*s", dataCount, sockdat->buffer + 6); 
    } else if(dataCount == 127) { // Unmask the payload for a 127 byte message or larger
        for (ix = 0; ix < dataCount; ix++) {
            sockdat->buffer[8 + ix] ^= mask[ix % 4];
        }
        rc = asprintf(&sockdat->dataUnmasked, "%.*s", dataCount, sockdat->buffer + 8);
    }
    log_printf(3,"dataafter: %s",sockdat->dataUnmasked);
}
```

The data is all handled in a global structure.  dataUnmasked being the data output in this function and &sockdat->buffer is the input.

What the output of this function should be is:

databefore: ▒▒cy▒▒\ðOI▒▒SU▒▒i
dataafter: ?jog,0,10,10\n

Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: Are you interpreting the data according to the correct byte ordering?

Comment: To my knowledge yes.  Although I will triple check just incase. It is defined in RFC 6455 section 5.3.

Comment: Could you post the content of your sockdat->buffer (at least first 10-15) bytes in form of octal numbers or similar?

Comment: sockdat->buffer octal: 1001420540

Comment: I mean those bytes containing the message you are parsing. I mean, your databefore:▒▒cy▒▒\ðOI▒▒SU▒▒i as octal numbers so that we can see what each ▒ is.

Comment: databefore: ▒▒▒Ӗ▒▒▒▒ڤ▒▒Ƹ▒▒
sockdat->buffer octal: 1001420600 1001420601 1001420602 1001420603 1001420604 1001420605 1001420606 1001420607 1001420610 1001420611 1001420612 1001420613 1001420614 1001420615 1001420616 1001420617 1001420620 1001420621 1001420622
 dataafter: ▒
▒